# Gradle - only execute a task if code in a directory has changed

Tags: gradle, kotlin

I have a Gradle task that creates a 100MB JAR. Now I only want it to be created as part of my `gradle build` if code within the project has changed (say a specific `./src` directory).

So at the moment the build.gradle.kts looks like:

```
tasks {
    "shadowJar"(ShadowJar::class) {
        isZip64 = true
        archiveFileName.set("${project.name}.jar")
        dependencies {
            include(dependency(".*:.*:.*"))
            exclude(dependency("org.apache.spark:.*"))
        }
    }
}

tasks {
    "build" {
        dependsOn("shadowJar")
    }
}
```

Any ideas on how I can achieve this?

Thanks

p.s.
And as a background I'm doing to improve the build time. I've already found 2 things for my `gradle.properties`:

```
org.gradle.parallel=true
org.gradle.caching=true
```

Comment: Did you find any solution? I find my problem by adding -i to gradle. It did show the file that had changed."./gradlew shadowJar -i"

Comment: Nope - didn't figure out a concrete solution - I couldn't figure out exactly what was changing the files - maybe some timestamp.

Answer (score 5):

In general if you want to tell a task how to know whether it's up-to-date or not, you need to define `inputs` and `outputs`. These are what tells Gradle if a task is up-to-date or not. If nothing has changed in the inputs or outputs since the task was last run, Gradle knows it's up-to-date and will not re-execute the task.

In your case the inputs would be the source folder, and the outputs would be the jar.  This is explained in the Gradle docs [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:up_to_date_checks).  You can see an example in [this](https://guides.gradle.org/running-webpack-with-gradle/#step_3_declare_task_inputs_and_outputs) article, which shows how Gradle can call Webpack, but only if something has changed.

So you could do something like this:

```
tasks {
    "shadowJar"(ShadowJar::class) {
        // all the stuff you already have, plus these two new lines:
        inputs.dir("... the source dir ...")
        outputs.file("... the generated jar ...")
    }
}
```

However, I presume the `shadowTask` task you're using is from here: https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow ? If so, you might not actually need to set the `inputs` and `outputs` directly as the task already sets them itself. For example if you look at the source code for that plugin you can see it annotates one method with `@InputFiles` (see [here](https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow/blob/3feb64280bb54c4a94bb5a8cf28d4769f8426f94/src/main/groovy/com/github/jengelman/gradle/plugins/shadow/tasks/ShadowJar.java#L98)). This, according to the docs:

> Marks a property as specifying the input files for a task.

The outputs are also specified in one of the superclasses (`AbstractArchiveTask.getArchiveFile`).

Comment: Thanks, so I gave that a go using: `inputs.dir("./src")` and `outputs.file("./build/libs/match-work.jar")` but it still went and spent a minute creating the JAR. Any ideas?

Comment: Looking into it a bit more, it says:

`Output property '$1' file /Users/x/Documents/GitProjects/work/apps/spark-jobs/ma/build/libs/match-work.jar has changed.` and

  `Output property 'archiveFile' file /Users/x/Documents/GitProjects/work/apps/spark-jobs/ma/build/libs/match-work.jar has changed.`

Comment: I think there must be something else at play then. I just tried with a simple project with just one class in it, and `shadowJar` was executed the first time I ran the build, but on subsequent runs it said it was up-to-date and skipped it. Maybe try creating a new cut-down project yourself to check if the task is skipped. If not, maybe you can put it on GitHub and we can look at it. Also, have updated my answer with some specifics around the `shadowJar` task.

Comment: Can I just confirm how you specified the directories: I'm using `inputs.dir("${project.projectDir}/src/")` and `outputs.file("./build/libs/${project.name}.jar")`

Comment: In the end I didn't even need to specify them: it knew by itself what the inputs and outputs were. But if you look at the [Webpack example](https://guides.gradle.org/running-webpack-with-gradle/#step_3_declare_task_inputs_and_outputs) you'll see it's using paths relative to the root of the project. e.g. if you have a `src` folder at the top level and you want that to be the input, just use `inputs.dir("src")`.